# Mapping data from Firebase Realtime Database Map<String, dynamic>);

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having issues mapping data from Firebase RTBD. I have a function called getUsers. In my User class I have the function rtdbFromMap to map the data I read from Firebase RTBD. The read works fine since I was able to print out data.value and it is what I expected. However, the execution gets hung on the rtdbFromMap line. I get no console errors, basically nothing happens. Any suggestion is appreciated!

```
  Future<void> getUsers(User myUser, List<User> otherUsers) async {
    for (var i = 0; i <= widget.otherUserIDs.length - 1; i++) {
      if (widget.otherUserIDs[i] != myUser.userID!) {
        DataSnapshot data =
            await usersRef.child(widget.otherUserIDs[i].toString()).get();
        print(data.value);
        User nextUser = User.rtdbFromMap(data.value as Map<String, dynamic>);
        print(nextUser.userFirstName);
        otherUsers.add(nextUser);
      }
    }
  }

 User.rtdbFromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    userImageUrls = data['userImageUrl'];
    userFirstName = data['userFirstName'];
    userID = data['userID'];
    userLastName = data['userLastName'];
  }
```

Comment: Does the execution stop, or doesn't anything happen? The call `.rtdbFromMap` doesn't do anything, you do not store the user object or anything. What do you want it to do?

Comment: I thought the rtdbFromMap is storing data in the nextUser object?

Comment: i have overlooked that line, you are right. Can you assure that the parsing from `data.value` to a map functions properly?